# Set of n numbers with mean average of each subset an integer

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Show that for any natural number "n" there exists a set of "n" elements such that the mean average of the elements of any non-empty subset of this set is an integer.

I have tried to consider that such a set exists for each n and starting from there to try and see how each element would look like and try to construct somehow the set:
if a(1)+....+a(n) will be in nZ
and a(1)+....+a(n-1) will be in (n-1)Z
then a(n)=nb(n)-(n-1)b(n-1)
Recursively, a(2)=2b(2)-b(1) and a(1)=b(1), where b(i) are all integers. However I don't see how I can now construct a set of this form such that that property holds.
I have also realized that because any subset of two elements must have a mean average in Z, all elements must be either all odd or all even.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: @EthanBolker I have added my tries to approach this question. However I got stuck really early and don't feel like I found a really good way to approach this question yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we only have to show the existence of such a set, constructing one completes our work here. Take a set of any $n$ multiples of $n!$. The average of elements in any subset being an integer is then trivial.